# New BrowserWindow loadFile not defined when webpacked

Tags: webpack, electron, webpack-4

I'm trying to use webpack 4 for my electron app.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.18.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js is (notice target is electron-main):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './main/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    target: 'electron-main'
}
```

I did:

1. `npm init -y`
2. Added to `package.json` `"main": "dist/main.bundle.js"`.
3. Created `./main/index.js` with contents from electron quick start - https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app - (just changed require to import and path to app/index.html):

   ```
   import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

   // Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
   // be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
   let win;

   function createWindow() {
       // Create the browser window.
       win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });

       // and load the index.html of the app.
       win.loadFile('app/index.html');

       // Open the DevTools.
       win.webContents.openDevTools();

       // Emitted when the window is closed.
       win.on('closed', () => {
           // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
           // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
           // when you should delete the corresponding element.
           win = null
       });
   }

   // This method will be called when Electron has finished
   // initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
   // Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
   app.on('ready', createWindow);

   // Quit when all windows are closed.
   app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
       // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
       // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
       if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
           app.quit()
       }
   });

   app.on('activate', () => {
       // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
       // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
       if (win === null) {
           createWindow();
       }
   });

   // In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
   // code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
   ```
4. I created `dist/app/index.html` with content:

   Hello World!

   ## Hello World!

   We are using node document.write(process.versions.node),
       Chrome document.write(process.versions.chrome),
       and Electron document.write(process.versions.electron).
5. I run `npx webpack` and its succesful.

However when I do `electron .` I get `win.loadFile` is undefined. Here is screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHMdR.png

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this setup with Electron, React, Sass and Webpack 4 will give you some ideas... https://github.com/wende60/Electron-Webpack4-React-Sass

regards, jo

Comment: Thanks @Joachim. I actually ended up just using babel with its typescript transpilation. Webpack was messing stuff up, and was really overkill for just wanting to transpile some code.